# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Tags: reactjs, api

I am new to learning React and I want to fetch something by making an API call which seems to not work for me. For the following code, I am getting an error in the console mentioned in the title.

The error is showing in the fetch statement for the below code and I am not been able to rectify it. What I am doing here is fetching the latitude and longitude of a position and passing it to a URL to fetch the weather.

import React, { Component } from "react"

```
class WeatherData extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      weatherReport:[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      const lat =  position.coords.latitude;
      const lon = position.coords.longitude;
    fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+{lat}+'&lon='+{lon}+'&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ weatherReport: data.main}));
    });
    
}
  render(){
    const  { weatherReport }  = this.state;

    
    return(
      <div>
          {weatherReport.temp}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WeatherData;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the difference between using the `function` keyword, and the "fat arrow" syntax (`=>`)

The `function` keyword created a new "`this` context" while the fat arrow inherits the parent context.
In other words, when you use `function`, the value of the `this` keyword becomes something new inside of that function, whereas, with `=>`, it remains the same as it was outside of the function.

You can read more about the `this` keyword here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

And more on the difference between `function` and `=>` can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

---

So, instead of writing this:
`getCurrentPosition(function(position) {`

You should write this:
`getCurrentPosition((position) => {`

Full example:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"

class WeatherData extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weatherReport: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => { // <- this is what has changed
      const lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const lon = position.coords.longitude;
      fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + { lat } + '&lon=' + { lon } + '&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ weatherReport: data.main }));
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { weatherReport } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {weatherReport.temp}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WeatherData;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a function using the `function` keyword when getting the geolocation - this gives a new `this` reference to anything inside its scope, including the arrow function and its contents. Use a fat arrow function, which binds the current `this` to its child blocks, to maintain the correct scope when using callbacks.

Also, not sure why you are chaining an object in the url like that:

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => { // this line
        const lat = position.coords.latitude;
        const lon = position.coords.longitude;
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({
            weatherReport: data.main
          }));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Although I imagine this was just a typo, I feel it's necessary to point out that both the function the OP wrote and your updated function are anonymous. A function being anonymous simply means it does not have a name. `function myName() {}` is **not** anonymous, but `function () {}` is anonymous.

Comment: You're correct, I have updated for clarity. Thank you